# When to stop reviewing code?

Tags: code-reviews

I am working in a team of 4 members. we have started reviewing code 2 months ago. we are using Gerrit as code review tool. while reviewing code initially we have found lot's of problem in the code i.e. no proper code comments. method are too big. no null pointer checking. no proper exception handling etc.

but now a days it looks code has improved. so when i am reviewing code i am not getting that much problem in the code.

so my question is should we continue code review even there is not that much flaws in the code? or will we stop?

Comment: same answer to when to stop unit testing. **NEVER**

Comment: If your team runs out of productive things to do, (i.e. running out of new features to implement, which is very common these days) then what choice do you have? Soon it will become checking the spelling and the naming standard of the variables.

Answer (score 9):

You can do whatever works for you, but don't your code reviews show up **real bugs** (and not only "beauty issues")? I have seldom seen a situation where new code did not have enough bugs to justify a review.

Besides that, don't your reviews make sure there is at least one second person (apart from the author) who knows the code? And if you would stop doing regular code reviews, don't you expect the issues you have listed above will probably come back (at least, occasionally)?

So answer those question for yourself, then you know if stopping regular code reviews is a good or bad idea.

Comment: Beauty is for Lint (or fxcop, or whatever code beautifier you have available to you).  The review team should not be spending time with superficial concerns.

Comment: yes, that make senses. the issue i have listed above might come back  and our code review also make sure there is at least one second person(apart from the author) knows the code. so i believe  the code review should be a continuous process. great answer!

Answer (score 5):

> no proper code comments. method are too big. no null pointer checking. no proper exception handling etc.

Some of these are just small problems that code review can catch.

Big methods and wrong exception are indeed problems, and it sounds like you are not doing unit testing (or at least not properly).

What is more important are big things :

- design issues - it is important to detect design issues sooner, rather then later
- to familiarize with other's code - you never know when someone is going to leave
- learn something new - someone may suggest new ideas

Comment: yes, you are right. we are not doing unit testing properly. but we are doing UI Testing. using Robotium for android and SWTBot for eclipse RCP. i also agree with your important points that you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

To put it clear, code review is **not really for spotting bugs** (even if it might do it), that is testing. **Code review's purpose is mainly to keep project patterns, clean code, avoid local solutions.**

To use a tool is useful, but it always worths the time and effort for a four eyes check to keep up good practices in the project. Even more senior programmers should let their code being subjected to a code review. The practices sometimes getting outdated or rethinked.
In Java I can recommend Adam Bien's works on rethinking old patterns. If the team is heterogenous (various workplace past + age), the regular code review is vital to avoid chaotic coding.

Just to mention an obvious reason why to spend time on code review: if the code is reviewed and becomes homogenous in practices, anybody can go on vacation without constant bugging about their solutions. Since the code is similar, others can actually deal with even the unfamiliar modules of the program in case of bugfixing. Also if somebody leaves from the project, there will be no modules with horrible solutions which nobody understands.

So when to stop? **Never.** The regular code review pays back in long run. Makes the code easier to maintain.

Comment: Part of the goal of code reviews is absolutely spotting bugs. Testing will never catch everything, so multiple defect detection techniques should be used. See [Code Complete](http://www.cc2e.com/), Table 20-2 for details on defect detection rates of various methods.

Comment: @MikePartridge I agree on a certain level, but I more tend to say, bug spotting is a by-product of code review. The main goal of the code review is a system of assuring the code quality. Auto and manual tests are for bug spotting.

Comment: Code quality and defect detection are both products of code reviews. I recommend you read chapter 20 "The Software Quality Landscape" of Code Complete. It opened my eyes.

Comment: Though I agree with most things you wrote, I would like to add one remark. The OP mentioned "no null pointer checking" and "no proper exception handling". Actually, I call this bugs, not just "messy code" or "local solutions".

Comment: I couldn't disagree more. What you are describing as the purpose of code reviews are the least important reasons. FINDING BUGS is the overwhelming reason for code reviews. The other stuff is just a by product. Code reviews take a lot of time. If the purpose of code reviews is what you describe then there aren't going to be many (if any) customers willing to pay for them. Customers will pay for code reviews because they believe it will find bugs sooner rather than later, like when they are 30,000 feet in the air.

Comment: @Dunk I don't mind disagreement, I am sure code review is tyically not the customers' matter, it is in the core of code production. I mean it is not much to do of the input (specification) and output (product). I would say it should stay deep in the black box of code production.

Comment: @Cs:In order to have your company certified for adhering to various standard processes (e.g. ISO/MIL-STD/IEEE/DoD) you have to document the process. Code Review is very much a part of those certifications. That also means its part of the bid process and code review time is quoted as a separate activity. So it can't be some hidden task in many cases. Even if it were, if finding bugs and identifying uncovered what if scenarios weren't the key component then it is really a waste of time compared to other tasks developers could be doing with their time instead, like getting the product working.